# I'm trying to set up Apps Script to send emails for an Order Form from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created an Google Form so our employees can request their needs, it's a basic Order Form. I am receiving all their request in a Google Sheet and I'm trying to send them an email responding to their request. In my spread sheet I have a column called "Approval Status" with a drop down with the options "Approved", "Denied" and "Have Questions". What I'm trying to achieve is based on my "Approval Status" the person who made the request should receive an email with the response.

I've used the link below as reference. So far so good, until I get to step 5.3. I have tried editing the rows but I get a "ReferenceError: column is not defined". The error is coming from the shouldSendEmail function.

Here's my code and a picture of my spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXq3D.png)

```
function sendEmailsAndUpdateStatus() {
 //Get the rows in the spreadsheet
 var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();
 var data = dataRange.getValues();

 //Remove the header row and add it to a new array.
 //We will write this array back to the spreadsheet at the end.
 var updatedData = [data.shift()];

 //The variable numNotification will track if notifications were sent
 var numNotifications = 0;

 //Process each row using a forEach loop
 data.forEach(function (row) {
   //Check if email notifications should be sent and send them.
   //If the notification is sent, increment numNotifications and also
   //update the "Email sent" column to "Y".
   if(shouldSendEmail(row)) {
     sendApprovalStatusEmail(row);
     numNotifications++;
     row[9] = "Y";
   }

   //Add this row to the new array that we created above
   updatedData.push(row);
 });

 //Write the new array to the spreadsheet. This will update the
 //"Email sent" columns in the spreadsheet.
 dataRange.setValues(updatedData);

 //Display a Toast notification to let the user know if notifications
 //were sent.
 if(numNotifications > 0) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Successfully sent " + numNotifications + " notifications.");
 } else {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("No notifications were sent.");
 }
}

function shouldSendEmail(row) {
 //Don't send email unless the expense report has been processed
 if(column[7] != "Approved" && column[7] != "Rejected" && column[7] != "Have questions")
   return false;
  //Don't send email if email address is empty
 if(row[5] === "")
   return false;
  //Don't send email if already sent
 if(row[9] === "Y")
   return false;
  return true;
}

function sendApprovalStatusEmail(row) {
 //Create the body of the email based on the contents in the row.
 var emailBody = `
EXPENSE REPORT: ${row[7]}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Note: ${row[8] === "" ? "N/A" : row[8]}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Department: ${row[1]}
Amount: ${row[2]}
Reason: ${row[4]}
Date: ${(row[3].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + row[3].getDate() + "/" + row[3].getFullYear() }
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 Please contact expensereports@example.com if you have any questions about this email.
`;

 //Create the email message object by setting the to, subject,
 //body, replyTo and name properties.
 var message = {
   to: row[6],
   subject: "[Expense report " + row[7] + "]: " + row[4],
   body: emailBody,
   replyTo: "expensereports@example.com",
   name: "Expense Reports"
 }

 //Send the email notification using the MailApp.sendEmail() API.
 MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result? By the way, what is `until I get to step 5.3`? And, in your script, for example, `column` is not declared in `shouldSendEmail`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: This is my error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '7')
shouldSendEmail @ Code.gs:45

Comment: This was my fuide to create the Google Form and the code... 
https://spreadsheet.dev/expense-approval-workflow-using-google-forms-and-google-apps-script#use-apps-script-to-send-expense-report-approval-notifications